# create root crontab - having trouble setting DISPLAY

Tags: cron, synchronization

I am trying to set up a cron for syncing files with FreeFileSync, but I am running into file read permission errors. I thought an easy solution would be to create a cron job as root. The problem that I am running into is that I need to set DISPLAY=:0 in the command that is run by cron. As root, what would I set DISPLAY to?

Comment: So you want to run a command on a timer, as root, and display something on a users screen?

Comment: I want to run this cron job:
`0 18 * * *   DISPLAY=:0 /home/.../FreeFileSync /home/.../Sync.ffs_batch`

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207817/batch-freefilesync-job-with-crontab/1207855#1207855.

When I run the command 
`/home/...FreeFileSync /home/.../FreeFileSync/Sync.ffs_batch`

straight from the command line, I get some permission errors. So I try with sudo, the errors disappear. I want to use the "root" cron service, but I get an error because DISPLAY is not set correctly when I run the command from root cron. `Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?`

Comment: Yes I see that you are trying to run a command that displays to the users screen, but how should this work? What if no one is logged in. What if the user presses the wrong button? …